# Problems with cell borders in Excel document created with apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have generated an Excel document in `.xlsx` format, created on apache poi 3.13. When I upload the document to desktop excel, the borders of one cell disappear and in addition, the cell is expanded. And when uploading to online excel (google docs) everything works correctly.

1. Desktop Excel, the problem with borders where cell data and cell border 3-4 A cell is not completely filled as [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXzIB.png)
2. Online Excel version as [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhVvN.png)

Cell styling code

```
XSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setWrapText(true);
style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
style.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
style.setFont(font);
     
XSSFCellStyle baseStyle = getBaseStyle(style, workbook);
...
public static XSSFCellStyle getBaseStyle(CellStyle style, XSSFWorkbook wb) {
   XSSFCellStyle baseStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
   baseStyle.cloneStyleFrom(style);
   baseStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
   baseStyle.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
   baseStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
   baseStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);

return baseStyle;
}
```

Comment: Please put all information in the question. Do not refer to external sites. If they go down noone will understand what you are looking at.